# String to symbol in hash

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to turn a string into a symbol during a hash creation? That is, if I have a string `application_id` and I want to create a hash value `:application_id => '1234A'`, how would I do this?

I've tried to do something like `application_id.to_sym => id` but this didn't work.

Edit: I'm trying to make it work in a function. My function declaration would be something like:

```
def merge(external_id, id, opts)
  connection.upsert(external_id, external_id.to_sym => id, opts)
end
```

and I would call it by doing `merge('application_id', '1234A', {FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Smith'})`.

Unfortunately, this is giving me the error that it is expecting a `=>` instead of a `)`.

Comment: `application_id.class #=> String`

Comment: That should work fine, and is the normal way to do it. Show us the code where it "didn't work" so we can confirm the problem.

Comment: I updated my question with specific code I'm attempting to use.

Comment: The `connection` method provides an object that is the receiver of either `Hash#merge` or of the `merge` being defined here.  It can't be the former, as that merge takes a single argument (the hash to be merged) and an optional block.  It therefore appears that this `merge` is recursive and will keep adding to the stack as long as `connection` keeps feeding instances of its class.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Please say what `connection` is, and what you want your `merge` method to do with the parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the function names to be distinct. `connection` is a connection to a database object, and `upsert` is a function on that connection (not through ActiveRecord).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert string to symbol:

```
'application_id'.to_sym => id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {}
str = "application_id"
h[str.to_sym] = "1234A"
p h # => {:application_id=>"1234A"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a way to do this in place

```
id = 5
bar = "foo"
{
  :"#{bar}" => id
}
```

returns

```
{:foo => 5}
```

so you could do

```
{ :"#{'application_id'}" => id }
```

Comment: This is terribly inelegant and non-idiomatic. Ruby will automatically handle embedding a bad symbol name inside double-quotes if you use `to_sym`: `'foo bar'.to_sym # => :"foo bar"`. Both "foo" and "application_id" are valid symbol names and work without needing double-quotes, so don't muddy the water: `'foo'.to_sym # => :foo` and `'application_id'.to_sym # => :application_id`.

Comment: Of course they both work but I fail to see why it so strongly upsets your sense of elegance.The examples above are slightly ridiculous, but I see nothing wrong with defining a symbol like this `:"#{first_name}_#{last_name}"` instead of `"#{first_name}_#{last_name}".to_sym`

Comment: Or `[first_name, last_name].join('_').to_sym` and let Ruby decide if it needs wrapping double-quotes? `application_id` is already a string so there's no need to interpolate it into another string just to get it inserted in double-quotes. Ruby will do the right thing using `to_sym` so there's no need to jump through hoops.

Answer (score 0):

It is conceivable that you want just

```
connection.merge(application_id: '1234A', FirstName: 'John', LastName: 'Smith').
```